# What are the formulas behind the Cronbach's alpha method?

Tags: statistics

My goal is to implement a Cronbach's alpha method to a statistics software. I was able to compute the alpha values by R using the following code:

```
> library(psych)
> MyData <- read.csv(file="C://Users//Jaakko Seppälä//Downloads//Aineisto.csv", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
> alpha(MyData)

Reliability analysis   
Call: alpha(x = MyData)

  raw_alpha std.alpha G6(smc) average_r S/N    ase mean   sd
      0.94      0.94    0.96      0.36  15 0.0052  3.5 0.63

 lower alpha upper     95% confidence boundaries
0.93 0.94 0.95 

 Reliability if an item is dropped:
      raw_alpha std.alpha G6(smc) average_r S/N alpha se
```

Now, I would like to know the formulas behind  those variables. I tried to use Google and found https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf page 361. But it was hard for me to read it as there weren't explained all symbols, like is $tr$ trace or $t\cdot r$. So is it possible that someone explains me how to compute the variables given in an output? I also saw that Cross Validated won't allow the question if it focuses on programming.

Comment: You only need to know the interpretation of covariance (as a matrix) see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix then recall the diagonal of the matrix will give the variances. the rest is well explained in the file you sent.